# Holder continuity and Hilber space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \Re^n$ be an open set and let $u \in H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ be a weak solution of $\Delta u=f $ in $\Omega$, with $f \in C^{0,\alpha}(\Omega)$. Prove that $u \in C^{2,\alpha}(K)$ for any compact $K \subset \Omega$.

Comment: You have stated what you are asking, but it would help others if you also mention the context of the problem, and what you have tried. That helps people write more helpful answers and avoid telling you things you already know. Also, some users on this site find it impolite for questions to be asked as commands ("Prove that ...").

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard theorem in elliptic PDE: see the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger or the lecture notes [Regularity for Poisson equation](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.11f/lec11.pdf) by Xinwei Yu. Starting from scratch, the proof takes several pages. The basic idea is to consider the Newtonian potential of $f$ (call it   $v$), which is shown to be in $C^{2,\alpha}$ by direct estimates. The difference  $u-v$ is harmonic in the weak sense, hence (Weyl's lemma) in the classical sense,  hence $u-v\in C^\infty$.